# Novel about a soldier (with psychic powers) post a war looking for his old comrades

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this novel a long time back. Don't remember the name and much of the story. But anyways, before the present time of the story, around half a century back, the world was plunged into a period of continuous long wars and violence. It was only about four years before the present time of the story that the war came to an end, the world getting united and achieving peace under the empire 'Trinity' (conglomeration of US, China and Russia).

The story follows a soldier who fought in that war. He was part of group/corps who fought against the empire since the empire was targeting their group for a long time. That group/corp consisted of people like him who were psychic and/or control elemental powers related to nature. He joins the groups sometime after his parents were killed at a young age. With the hopes to put an end to the war and the violence plaguing the world.

However, they were defeated by the empire. Having become the losers of the war the empire vilified them as perpetrators of the war and set out to eliminate the remaining. Some of the survivors of the group killed themselves out of shame, failure and disgrace as they realized in the end they were still useless and only prolonged the war, bloodshed and suffering.

Story follows the protagonist searching for his old comrades while on the run from the empire. However, a new group of psychic users have also arisen that are willing do anything to achieve power/control over the world. Eventually the protagonist is able to find and meet up a few of his comrades. But they fear that another war is about to start because of the new psychic group. A repeat of the previous era war and further vilifying the image of psychic/elemental people. They also find out to their shock that one of their friend/comrade who they though died in the war is also part of this new group.

Anyone know this novel. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Great start! You could help by adding information like when you read the novel, whether it was new at the time, if you read it in another language than English, details about the cover, any names of characters, etc.. Also, was "Trinity" the actual name of the conglomerate or just your name for it?